# How to count and group using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have the following data returned from a web service and serialized into a list:

```
Name             Severity      Type     
John Doe         Warning       A        
John Doe         Error         A 
John Doe         Error         A 
John Doe         Error         A      
Jane West        Error         B        
Mike Smith       Warning       B        
Jack Black       Warning       A
```

In vb.net, I want to summarize it into the following:

```
Name       TypeAWarning    TypeAError  TypeBWarning   TypeBError
John Doe        1              3                          
Jane West                                                1
Mike Smith                                 1
Jack Black      1
```

Using linq, how can I take this collection and summarize it?  I tried something like:

```
 Dim data As New List(Of TempData)

data.add(new TempData ({TypeAWarning = from d in data Group d By Name = a.Severity into Group??
```

I am just not sure if linq is the way to go.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.110).aspx) to group items by `Name` field, then knowing each group contains the key (`Name` field) and all items of the group, you can use this query to shape the result:

```
Dim Result = Items.GroupBy(Function(item) item.Name) _
                  .Select(Function(group) New TempData() With
                  {
                      .Name = group.Key,
                      .TypeAWarning = group.Where(Function(item) item.Type = "A" And item.Severity = "Warning").Count(),
                      .TypeAError = group.Where(Function(item) item.Type = "A" And item.Severity = "Error").Count(),
                      .TypeBWarning = group.Where(Function(item) item.Type = "B" And item.Severity = "Warning").Count(),
                      .TypeBError = group.Where(Function(item) item.Type = "B" And item.Severity = "Error").Count()
                  }).ToList()
```